# I am not able to retrieve values from my sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s=e1.getText().toString();
                Cursor cr=db.rawQuery("select * from tbl_notes",null);
                cr.moveToFirst();
                int i=cr.getColumnIndex("save_text");
                String chr=cr.getString(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+chr+""+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                insert(s);
            }
        });

}
public long insert(String ch)
{
    ContentValues initialvalues = new ContentValues();
    initialvalues.put("save_text", ch);
    return db.insert("tbl_login",null,initialvalues);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your database with `getWritableDatabase()`

**Note:** Also you should check if `cursor` isn't `null` before running `moveToFirst()` in order to avoid NullPointerException.